# how to pass array as a parameter to a function in C?

Tags: c, arrays, function, parameters

I have the following array in C:

```
int format[6][6] = { {1,1,1,1,1,1},
                     {2,2,2,2,2,2},
                     {3,3,3,3,3,3},
                     {4,4,4,4,4,4},
                     {5,5,5,5,5,5},
                     {6,6,6,6,6,6}
}
```

then I have a function need to pass array `format` to the function, and copy all the data to a new array:

```
void constructNewArray(int array[6][6])
{
    int newArray[10][10] = {0};
    memcpy(newArray, array, sizeof(int)*6*6);
}
```

So the parameter of `constructNewArray` function, is `int array[6][6]` right for as a parameter? or how to correct it?

Comment: I would debate any real life "need" of this kind.

Comment: ``void constructNewArray(int **array)`` might be what you are looking for?

Comment: ok, then what is the right way to pass such array to a function?

Comment: You are doing wrong here: int newArray[10][10] = {0};

Comment: *"how to correct it?"*?? You haven't even told us what the problem is!

Comment: I am not sure if the code there is right, so, if it is not right, how to correct it?

Comment: There are different levels of 'rightness'. Syntactically, the function is fine. However, it doesn't do anything with the array it has created, so it is also pointless. The question for you (@user2131316) to answer is: how are you going to use the new array?  Are you going to call some other function from within the function shown, or are you going to try and pass the new array back to the calling function in some way? Is the calling function going to need to pass in the storage for the new array, so you're really initializing rather than constructing it? What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2):

As written, the code in the function is 'OK'; the function definition is OK. As [abelenky](https://stackoverflow.com/users/34824/abelenky) points out, the semicolon is missing from the array initializer in the calling code.

The leading dimension to the array is substantially ignored by the compiler.  If you've got a C99 compiler, you could write:

```
void constructNewArray(int array[static 6][6])
```

That tells the compiler that it can assume there will be at least 6 rows in the array.  I'm not sure when that really provides a benefit, but the facility is there.

What's less clear is whether the data is copied to your 10x10 array the way you want.  You'll actually end up with the array initialized as though you'd written:

```
int newArray[10][10] =
    { { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, },
      { 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, },
      { 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, },
      { 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, },
      // ... all zeroes from here onwards
    };
```

Also, the compiler will not complain if you try to pass a 10x6 or 2x6 matrix to the function.

As it stands, your function carefully creates the array and initializes it, and then does nothing with it.  You can't return a (pointer to) a local array.  You'd have to do dynamic memory allocation for that, or you'd pass the new array as a parameter to the function, in which case it becomes 'initialize 10x10 array from 6x6 array'.  Or you could arrange to call another function with the constructed array from inside the `constructNewArray()` function, but that's implausible for a function named 'construct'. So, it is not yet clear that your function is properly designed.

Comment: The code as written is not entirely "ok".  He's missing a semi-colon at the end of his `format` array.

Answer (score 1):

This definition is ***wrong***

```
int format[6][6] = { {1,1,1,1,1,1},
                     {2,2,2,2,2,2},
                     {3,3,3,3,3,3},
                     {4,4,4,4,4,4},
                     {5,5,5,5,5,5},
                     {6,6,6,6,6,6}
}
```

All variable declarations end with a semi-colon.
This should be:

```
int format[6][6] = { {1,1,1,1,1,1},
                     {2,2,2,2,2,2},
                     {3,3,3,3,3,3},
                     {4,4,4,4,4,4},
                     {5,5,5,5,5,5},
                     {6,6,6,6,6,6}
};  // <== NOTE the final semi-colon.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
void constructNewArray(int array[][6])
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The method you have used to pass the array into `constructNewArray` is correct. When passing a general multidimensional array, let's say `data[a][b]...[x]`, you should specify all the dimensions except the first one. For example, you could declare `constructNewArray` like this:

```
void constructNewArray(int array[][6])
```

Another way you can pass an array to a function is using a pointer.

```
void constructNewArray(int **array)
```

You can still access the elements using indexing like `array[1][2]` inside `constructNewArray` with this method.

Comment: ok, but if I use void constructNewArray(int array[][6]), is it right to memcpy(newArray, array, sizeof(int)*6*6); like this?

Comment: @user2131316 memcpy does not care whether what you have passed to it is an array or not. It will copy `sizeof(int)*6*6` bytes of data starting at address `array` and copy it to `newArray`. It you want to do that, it is up to you.

Comment: ok, then in this case, what is the right way to copy the data?

Comment: @user2131316 You need to clarify what you mean by copying the data. What do you want the resulting array to look like? As of now, it is definitely copying the data into `newArray`.

Comment: I have to copy everything from the array which is passed as a parameter to the new array newArray inside of this function